# ARKit – Track more than one person by VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

Is there any way to track multiple bodies using `VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest` and work with resulted rigs in ARKit?

Comment: Thanks!! Just found an example, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/detecting_human_actions_in_a_live_video_feed